# Is there a way to have a looped scene to demo VR streaming performance on HTC VIVE?

Tags: video-streaming, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I want to find the best setup to stream a VR experience over Wi-Fi.
To be able to play with different connection settings, it would be great if I could run a VR game or demo all the time, rather than having to be there and move things around.

This would allow to track the FPS more accurately and assess if the streaming is good enough.

Do you know how to do it?
What I've found so far is the "Playlist mode" but that does not include any automation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing in Unity you can try this: https://github.com/andrewjc/VRRecorder